# c++ check if varargs contain

Tags: c++

Is there a simple api (without loop) to check if varargs contain some value (char*)?

If there is no simple API , how should i iterate without any args count?

My method should be able to filter the log base on configuration IP ,so i need to check if one of the args is 10.3.2.2 (some configuration IP).

```
void Logger::Log(const char *format, ...) {
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(mtx_);
    if (!file_) {
        file_ = fopen("application.log", "w");
    }
    time_t current = time(0);
    tm *ptm = localtime(&current);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "\n[" << ptm->tm_min << ":" << ptm->tm_sec << "]";
    fprintf(file_, ss.str().data());
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    vfprintf(file_, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fflush(file_);
}
```

looking on this [lesson](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html) , show only iterate with given args length and types.
format and than check contain is expensive and logger should be able to support in highly performance demands.

my target is to implement simple logger method. so you will call it like this:

```
Log("trafic from ip %s to ip %s", "10.1.1.1","1.1.1.1")
```

and lots of other calls . in the filter i want to check if one of the parameter value is "10.1.1.1" (for example) , so don’t log it.

Comment: No, there is nothing that does this in C++.

Comment: You are incorrect that in the lesson, you are iterating given only the length. In that example, you are also given that all parameters are doubles. You need the types of the arguments as well as the length, which is a big issue in your case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are correct. i mean that i even dont have length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any syntactic sugar to do this because there is no universal way to know the types of the varargs. Without knowing the types, you can't get their values. So you'd have to write code to do this based on how your functions knows what types its arguments are.

You want to do this:

1. Assemble the entire log message in the `stringstream`.
2. Check the log message for the desired string.
3. If you find the string in there, make sure it is *not* preceded or followed by a digit.
4. If you found the string and it's not preceded or followed by a digit, log it.

You need that last check because "foo bar 12.3.4.5 baz" contains "2.3.4.5" as does "foo 2.3.4.51 bar". So if you find the string and it's followed or preceded by a digit, you still want to log the message.

Comment: You'll have to parse the format string, this is going to be a *very* painful thing to have to code. You'll have to understand and correctly process *every* format specifier that your function is allowed to take, figure out what argument type they require (if any) and skip that in the varargs. You have painted yourself into a corner and should either reconsider the design or take a "hope its good enough" approach and `strstr` the output from a temporary buffer.

Comment: As you said format and than check include can be expensive and my logger need to deal in strict performance demand.

Comment: You've painted yourself in to a corner. Back up and fix the design.

Comment: I don't know enough about your design to comment. What *precisely* is the problem you are trying to solve? (But most likely, the solution is to output entirely to the stringstream, and then look into the stream to see if the sub-string appears.)

Comment: Want to implement simple logger method. so you will call it like this: Log("trafic from ip %s to ip %s", "10.1.1.1","1.1.1.1") and lots of other calls . in the filter i want to check if one of the parameter value is "10.1.1.1" , so dont log it.

Comment: @user1495181: Then definitely just assemble the entire log message in the `stringstream` and search the output for the desired string. If you find the desired string in the output, make sure it isn't preceded or followed by a digit. If not, suppress the log entry. (Answer updated)

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. And anyway you shouldn't use varargs in c++, use variadic templates instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, no, there's no indexed access to the variable arguments list; just item by item, so you would have to loop through them; that's how `vprintf`, etc. work. When you iterate through the items you need to know how many there are and, usually, their types, and that's established by convention. For `vprintf`, etc., there must be at least as many items as there are format specifiers in the format string, and each format specifier tells you the expected type of the argument. Another convention that you could adopt would be to use a sentinel value to mark the end of the argument list; for homogeneous lists such as a list of pointers, a null pointer could be a workable sentinel.